# Transaction in hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I want to ask how transactions are validated in hyperledger fabric? To explain this I would like to add, as per my understanding, hyperledger fabric is permission project and even only two participants can make a transaction. So in this case (two person are making any transaction) anyone can make changes on later stage so i am confuse that how this is going to work with effecting immutability of blockchain?